# Search results sort order failing: set by date only

Tags: sql, sort

Hi the default wordpress search seems to be for "piano"

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
FROM wp_posts
WHERE 1=1
AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%piano%')
OR (wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%piano%')
OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%piano%')))
AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment')
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
OR wp_posts.post_author = 5
AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%piano%' DESC, wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT 0, 25
```

however I need them all sorted by date first. My search results by date are skewed:

```
2020-10-25  
2020-10-22  
2020-10-20  
2020-10-20  
2020-10-16  
2020-10-13  
2020-10-10  
2020-10-07  
2020-10-06  
2020-10-02  
2020-09-30  
2020-09-28  
2020-09-02  
2020-08-09  
2020-07-21  
2020-07-21  
2020-05-21  
2020-04-24  
2020-03-06  
2019-06-02  <- here it is skewed onwards
2019-06-01  
2020-10-25  
2020-10-24  
2020-10-23  
2020-10-23
```

So I asume it is because the SQL query sorts by title first.

So I tried this solution:

```
function changeSearchSort( $orderby, $query ){
    global $wpdb;

    if(!is_admin() && is_search()) {
        $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_date ASC";
    }
    return  $orderby;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','changeSearchSort',10,2);
```

from here
[How do I change WP search results order?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/339566/how-do-i-change-wp-search-results-order)

and it does not work.

I have tried this:
a) disabled all plugins
b) different themes

still not working.

Help appreciated

cheers

Ben

Comment: Where did you put your code - in the theme functions file?

Comment: Hi Sally, in my own plugin to act like a functions file...which I didnt disable but all others I did. I found a workaround to add this

`function my_archive_query_override( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'DESC' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'my_archive_query_override' );`

```
however it only adds the SQL query AFTER the one I shown above, so it doesnt alter the original wordpress query